# Realizar peticion ajax dentro de otra

Tags: jquery

Tengo un form donde consulto todas las ventas(tabla ventas) entre dos fechas, la tabla venta tiene idc el idcliente al que se le vendio.

Entonces como consulto para cada registro de venta el nombre del cliente de dicho id? Dado que quiero mostrar el nombre no el idcliente.

```js
$.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/reporte/procesoReporte.php",
            data: { "accion": "fecha","fechad":fechad,"fechah":fechah}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
$.ajax({

   
        type: "POST",
        url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
        data: {"accion":"obtener","id":data[i].idc}, 
         dataType:"json",
async:true,
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
       success: function(datas){
    
     nombreC=datas[0].nombre;
      }
});
 
            var newRow =
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + cant + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i][13] + '       ' +data[i][15] + "</td>" +
              
                "<td>" + precio + "</td>" + 
               
                "<td>" + subtotal + "</td>"+
                "<td>" + desc + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + (subtotal -  desc) + "</td>" +
                   
                         "<td>" + nombreC + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + "</td>" +"<td>"+
               
        
              
                "</tr>";
            $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
   

           
       
     }
            });
```

Probe hacerlo asi como dice arriba

Esta peticion tambien funciona bien, pero como anido las dos, esta bien poner ese codigo dentro del otro, pasandole data[i].idcliente al pedido ajax?

Comment: Ya has probado usar métodos asincrónicos de Jquery?, para que una vez termine una consulta hagala otra?

Comment: No,la verdad no.

Comment: puedes poner el segundo ajax dentro de una función que reciba un parametro que seria el id por el cual vas a buscar y en el success de la primera llamar a esta funcion pasandole como paremetro el id del cliente.

Comment: Ok lo voy a intentar

Comment: @MiguelClavijo Hola!, los eventos ajax si son asincronos y se ejecutan independientes del codigo que siga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero te ayude es un ejemplo de realizar funciones Ajax anidadas:

```
    var promise = $.ajax({
          url : window.location.href + "ajax1/",
          type : "POST", 
          data : { dato1: datos,
                   dato2: datos2,
                }, 
          success : function(json) {

              //Almacena el resultado en algún lado

            },

          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
        promise.then(function(){
            //
                    $.ajax({
                url : window.location.href + "ajax2/",
                type : "POST",
                data :  { datos1: datos1,
                         datos2: datos2,
                      },
                success: function(data2){
                  console.log(data2); // Debería imprimir {ajax2: true}
                },
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                  console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
              });
        //
    });
```

Espero te ayude :D

Comment: Ahi edite el contenido de la pregunta y puse un pedido dentro de otro pero no funciona

Comment: ¿Que error te sale?, por que a mi me funciona correctamente..

Comment: Como se ve en nombreC guardo el nombre obtenido del cliente, pero me dice undefinded en la tabla de ventas

Answer (score 1):

Decir que esta bien o mal es solo una opinion, pero te podrían aconsejar muchas cosas por hacer, lo más limpio es hacer funciones independientes para cualquier tipo de modificación no te cueste tanto encontrar el código.

```
var idCliente = 0;

function procesoReporte() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/reporte/procesoReporte.php",
        data: { "accion": "fecha","fechad":fechad,"fechah":fechah}, 
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(data){
            idCliente = data[i].idc;
        }
    })
}

function editarCliente(idCliente){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
        data: {"accion": "obtener", "id": idCliente}, 
        dataType:"json",
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(data){
            nombreC = data[0].nombre;
            idCliente = 0; //Reiniciar valor.
            alert(nombreC);
        }
    });
}   

function ejecutarReporte() {
    $.when(procesoReporte).then(editarCliente);
}
```

No pude probar el codigo xD pero cualquier cosa me avisas para editar, la linea `$.when(procesoReporte).then(editarCliente);` lo que hace es ejecutar `procesoReporte` y cuando termine y funcione ejecutar `editarCliente`, la variable `idCliente` ya esta creada y toma el valor cuando el servicio responde correctamente.